# How do I delete custom maps from my map list?

Tags: starcraft-2

How do I remove the custom maps I have "downloaded" from my map list? They are clutter and it is not like you get to try a map out first to see if it sucks before you are stuck with it forever.

Comment: They're likely stored locally on your system *somewhere*, but I'm not sure where to start looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So they're stored in: `C:\ProgramData\Blizzard Entertainment\Battle.net\Cache`, unfortunately that's not going to help you as they're hashed.  This makes it hard to tell which is which.

If only some kind soul would [invent a tool](http://www.clanttg.com/index.php?/topic/45-sc2-map-browser/) to solve this problem...

Comment: A tool would be nice, thanks for the link, I haz trust issues so I will have to code my own tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everythiing in the folder at:

C:\ProgramData\Blizzard Entertainment\Battle.net\Cache

*and* voila problem solved....good luck.